# dynamic routing AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to bind a `route` property to the src for `ng-include`:

**config.js**

```
$routeProvider.when('/services', {
  templatePATH: '/views/services.html'
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppController">
<body>
<div ng-include src="{{page}}" class="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**controllers.js**

```
controller('AppController', ['$scope','$route','$routeParams', function($scope, $route, $routeParams) {
  var render = function(){
    $scope.page = $route.current.templatePATH;
  };

  $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess",function( $currentRoute, $previousRoute ){
    render();
  });

}]).
```

[**Here's where I got the idea.**](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2420-Mapping-AngularJS-Routes-Onto-URL-Parameters-And-Client-Side-Events.htm) What is strange is that the value of `templateURL` can be seen in the DOM on pageload where `src` is injected from the `ng-include` directive. Sadly however, this is not working.

Is it possible to achieve this kind of convention?

Comment: could you please share fiddle demo or provide more detail on question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh your are just making a very small mistake please change your code to below

```
<div ng-include="page"  class="container"></div>
```

More Detailed Answer :
When you use ng-include directive a watch is put on srcExp which is value of attr.ngInclude || attr.src so if you do {{page}} then you will be watching on the value of page not on page property so you have to put "page" without interpolated value so that it can watch directly on page instead of page string value

Comment: Thanks, what a dumb mistake haha. I have a follow up to this you can also take a stab at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095989/detect-if-resource-exists-behind-rewrite-rules-with-javascript-and-angularjs