# How to change "src" attribute value of ng-include in angularJS after first load?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

On a keyboard event I want to change the `ng-include` directive's `src` value dynamically.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a code example that could help you:

```
<div class="example-animate-container" ng-include="{{template.url}}">
```

Then in directive or controller

```
$(document).on("keydown", function () {
    template.url = "put the value here";
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: You seem like you might be able to answer a simliar question of mine here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091713/dynamic-routing-angularjs

Comment: i have interpolated angular value in ng-include so when template.url will change ng-include will fetch the new url and on key press im changing template.url value which will update the source of ng-include automatically please give it a try and let me know if it solves your problem

Comment: I made it working by intercepting the keydown event in external jQuery keydown function, however as you said "Then in directive or controller", how can I do that? I mean, say I have a $scope.url variable in my controller, I want to write a keydown listener inside my same controller which will reset the $scope.url value on some keydown event.

Comment: if you go by angular standard you should avoid dom manipulation inside controller but still if you want to update dom inside controller then you can just use the keydown event inside the controller

Comment: I want to go by Angular way, so I won't put the dom manipulation inside controller. So where do I put it? in external jQuery script(like what I am doing now)? or in directive def? If directive def, then code example please. Thanks very much.

Comment: you should be definitley doing in directive see some examples here http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: it's a better practise to write: $scope.$apply(function() { /* do what you want here*/ })