# Does AngularJS have dynamic routing?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Does angular support dynamic routing at all?
Maybe some trick like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/:ctrl/:action', 
                     getRoute($routeParams.ctrl,$routeParams.action))

function getRoute(ctrl, action){
   return {
      templateUrl: ctrl+"-"+action+".html"
      controller: 'myCtrl'
   }
}
```

Please help me, I need to get templateUrl based out of routeParams

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091713/dynamic-routing-angularjs/17094459

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a late answer but I came across this problem myself, but it turns out that the solution by Dan conflicts with ngAnimate classes on the ngView directive, and the view is shown but the ng-leave animation will immediately be applied and hide the view opened with his dynamic routing.

I found the perfect solution [here](http://scriptogr.am/pploug/post/convention-based-routing-in-angularjs), and it's available in 1.1.5 +

In the `$routeProvider`, the `templateUrl` value can be a function, and is passed the route parameters:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/:page', {
         templateUrl: function(routeParams){
             return '/partials/'+routeParams.page+'.html';
        }
    })
});
```

Though the controller can't be given as a function so my solution is to give it in the template html as per usual with `ng-controller="HomeCtrl"`.

Using this solution we can route by convention in Angular.
I hope this helps others who weren't keen on manually adding every route to the routeProvider.

Comment: I've given this a +1 as it's exactly what I was after, the only thing thats missing is a way to handle missing templates i.e. the equivalent of .otherwise() as this will catch all routes. Any ideas?

Comment: I just googled and got this. This does works like a charm. But I wanted to know one thing. So.. when ever we click on a anchorTag the href get passed to the url as a param? And we pass that param by using routeParams?

Answer (score 3):

You want to bring it down to the controller level.

*In this example, I am overriding entire pages as well as partials by subdomain:*

**app.js**

```
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    template: 'home'
  });
  $routeProvider.when('/contact', {
    template: 'contact'
  });
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}])
```

**controllers.js**

```
controller('AppController', ['$scope','Views', function($scope, Views) {    
  $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess",function( $currentRoute, $previousRoute ){
    $scope.page = Views.returnView();
  });

  $scope.returnView = function(partial){
    return Views.returnView(partial);
  }    

}])
```

**services.js**

```
factory('Views', function($location,$route,$routeParams,objExistsFilter) {  

  var viewsService = {};
  var views = {
    subdomain1:{
      'home':'/views/subdomain1/home.html'
    },
    subdomain2:{

    },
    'global.header':'/views/global.header.html',
    'global.footer':'/views/global.footer.html',
    'home':'/views/home.html',
    'home.carousel':'/views/home.carousel.html',
    'contact':'/views/contact.html',
  };

  viewsService.returnView = function(partial) {
    var y = (typeof partial === 'undefined')?$route.current.template:partial;
    var x = $location.host().split(".");
    return (x.length>2)?(objExistsFilter(views[x[0]][y]))?views[x[0]][y]:views[y]:views[y];
  };

  viewsService.returnViews = function() {
  return views;
  };

  return viewsService;
}).
```

**filters.js**

```
filter('objExists', function () {
  return function (property) {
    try {
      return property;
    } catch (err) {
      return null
    }
  };
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-controller="AppController">
<body>
<ng-include src="returnView('global.header')"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="page"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="returnView('global.footer')"></ng-include>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I want to do, ie wordpress or modx style sites but with dynamic routes pulled into angular.  can you provide a working zip or something that I can get my hands on?  thanks!

Comment: @ZurielAndrusyshyn Upvote if it's helpful, the source is all right there.

Comment: is there a starting project i should be plugging this into?  on its own it seems incomplete?

Comment: @ZurielAndrusyshyn Understanding the fundementals of the framework is enough to intuitively understand how these pieces fit together. http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: thanks I am new to angular and have experimented with backbone.  I am working through a few things that I think you have already figured out.  If its not too much trouble can you email me? my contact info is on my profile page. Thanks!