# angular $routeProvider based on imported json?

Tags: json, angularjs

We're considering building our cms around angular and i'm wondering if there is a way to dynamically hook up routes in the config block based on an imported json file. We've been using the $routeProvider and listing out every page like this..

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'home'});
    $routeProvider.when('/archive', {templateUrl: 'partials/archive.html', controller: 'archive'});
}]);
```

That'd get a little out of hand to hand type that for a larger app/website. What I want to do is automate this process based on json input. Can anyone think of a way to go about that? I tried creating a service but only providers can get injected into the config block. Providers don't seem to actually execute any code in the config area, just set some options that will then be executed when that service is called later in the apps life..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution is to use dynamic routing for most routes, as I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154555/does-angularjs-have-dynamic-routing/21997865#21997865)

The `templateUrl` property can accept a function which is passed the `routeParams`, so this would enable straight forward routing by naming convention. If you have specific long routes you should place them before this catchall route.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/:page', {
    templateUrl: function(routeParams){
       return '/partials/'+routeParams.page+'.html';
    }
  })
});
```

Do note that the controller **can't** be passed as a function, so I simply include the controller in the top level element of the included partial using the usual `ng-controller=""` html attribute.

## EDIT:

If you do want to go with the json config I would advise you to inline it in the app config javascript rather than making a separate http get which would delay earliest user navigation on reload.
The code will look similar to the coffeescript answer below:

```
routes = [
  {route: "/home", vars: {templateUrl: "/partials/home", controller: "HomeCtrl"}},
  {...}
];

for(var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
  $routeProvider.when(routes[i].route,routes[i].vars);
}
```

I haven't come across libraries for this yet but it's probably best to make your own parser to match your routing conventions

Answer (score 1):

You can define route configuration as long as it is delivered with the initial page request to the application. This is because the route configuration needs to be defined at the same time that the application is defined. Otherwise, Angular wouldn't know how to behave. It also cannot be changed after the `config` function is run. I've demonstrated it with a Plunk here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/hKiWGib1ePuVISzXt4Wo?p=preview

You'll notice that the timeout replicates a call to the server. When it tries to modify `$routeProvider` configuration after the allotted time, there is no effect on the application. In order to get your configuration from an additional data request, your would first have to make sure that you both request and receive the route information before you bootstrap your angular application. In my opinion this is poor design of user experience seeing as the user would have to wait for an AJAX request before seeing anything on the page.

One more thing that you can take away from the example is that I had to use `setTimeout` instead of `$timeout`. This is due to the fact that you cannot inject services into the `config` function (and it is for reasons like this dynamic route injection example).

All in all, it comes down to this. Either, deliver the route configuration with the page, or create a complicated and ugly workaround for the Angular default functionality.